# Draw random bitmap in the onDraw method

Tags: android, bitmap, android-custom-view, ondraw

Firstly I am adding my cards to a list like that:

```
    private void initCards() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {  
    Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    scaledCardW = (int) (screenW/10); 
    scaledCardH = (int) (scaledCardW*1.28);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap,scaledCardW, scaledCardH, false);        
    deck.add(scaledBitmap); 

    }
```

But when it came to on draw method,my program is transforming a thing like an animation.
    My onDraw method is here:

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int left=newInteger.nextInt(screenW);
    int right=newInteger.nextInt(screenH);

    for(int i=0 ; i<k ;i++){
        canvas.drawBitmap(deck.get(i), left, right, null);
    }


}
```

These bitmaps must have random location and if I change the k from our main Activity different numbers of bitmaps must be drawen.Because of that,ı cannot remove the invalite() function.

Can anybody help me?Unfortunately,another topics about this problem are not providing my request.

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmaps keep moving because you are randomizing their position every time you draw. Try moving these lines:

```
left = newInteger.nextInt(screenW);
right = newInteger.nextInt(screenH);
```

into the same function that changes the value of k.